# What's the best move by white in this game?

Tags: analysis

[image: game]

In this game white must win. Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key move is the **g3** move.

- If the e3 rook is unpinned, black has lot's of troubles
- If the b8 knight is under-protected, Qxb8 wins easily

1.g3 achieves both.

```
 1.g3 Qc7 2.Rxd7 now wins (Qxb8 or Rxe8 coming)
```

Black should resign.

Comment: Variant Rxd7 - Rxd7 - too good )) 1. Rxd7 - Rxd7 2. g3 - ...

Comment: Works as well...

Comment: You were right with Rxd7...